# Navbar change back to transparent at top of page

Tags: javascript, css, navbar

I'm new to JavaScript and still figuring things out.

I've managed to get my nav to only appear at the top and on scrollup. The problem is I need it to return to a transparent background once it's at the top but it's staying grey after the change initiates.

```
/* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.background = "#2b2b2b";
    document.getElementById("totop").style.bottom = "-120px";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.background = "transparent";
    document.getElementById("totop").style.bottom = "0px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Comment: try to console.debug the values of prevScrollpos and currentScrollpos when you reach the top. That probably would explain why your condition still apply.

Comment: can you add your HTML

Comment: change `if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos)` to `if (prevScrollpos >= currentScrollPos || currentScrollPos <= document.getElementById("navbar").offsetHeight)`